# Why are the colors messed up in this Plot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color, grid-lines

I have a notebook which I cannot make to produce the accurate colors. I'll try to post the code hereafter. It looks a bit messy.

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

b1BlSmall = {4.17891*^-1, 5.59816*^-1, 7.09626*^-1, 4.17891*^-1};
b1BlLarge = {3.15389*^-1, 4.73084*^-1, 6.85972*^-1, 3.62698*^-1};
b2BlSmall = {9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1};
b2BlLarge = {9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 2.00000};
dbhAdult = {1.00000*^1, 1.00000*^1, 1.00000*^1, 5.48121};

C2B = 2.0
pftColor = {Green, Darker[Green], Darker[Darker[Green]], Magenta};

size2bl[dbh_,ipft_,a_:1,b_:1,c_:1]:=If[ipft!=4,\[Piecewise] b1BlSmall[[ipft]]/C2B*dbh^b2BlSmall[[ipft]] dbh<dbhAdult[[ipft]]
b1BlLarge[[ipft]]/C2B*dbh^b2BlLarge[[ipft]] True 

,\[Piecewise]   (a*b1BlSmall[[ipft]])/C2B*dbh^(b*b2BlSmall[[ipft]]) dbh<dbhAdult[[ipft]]
(a*b1BlLarge[[ipft]])/C2B*dbh^(c*b2BlLarge[[ipft]]) True
];

putzbl[dbh_] := (0.0856*dbh^2 - 0.376)/C2B;


Manipulate[
 Plot[{putzbl[dbh], 
   Evaluate@Table[size2bl[dbh, ipft, a, b, c], {ipft, 1, 4}]}, {dbh, 
   0.0, 11.0},
  PlotStyle -> Flatten[{Black, pftColor}]],
 {a, 0.8, 1.2}, {b, 0.8, 1.2}, {c, 0.8, 1.2}]
```

But the graph that I get is like[image]

Since I have five curves (the first is a function of its own, the last four are a family of functions of which only one is to manipulate) I was hoping to use a black line for the first curve and the four colors of pftColor for the latter. How do I do that?

**EDIT**

According to Kuba's answer:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Flatten@{putzbl[dbh], 
     Table[size2bl[dbh, ipft, a, b, c], {ipft, 1, 4}]}, {dbh, 0.0, 
   11.0},
  PlotStyle -> Flatten[{Black, pftColor}]],
 {a, 0.8, 1.2}, {b, 0.8, 1.2}, {c, 0.8, 1.2}]
```

Produce the correct behavior

Comment: Your code does not work (at least not in version 11.0.1). Can you make sure that your code works in a new notebook and using a fresh kernel (i.e., after Evaluation -> Quit Kernel)?

Comment: You need to come up with a simpler example.  The problem here is that you are using `PlotStyle ->{color1,{color2, color3, color4}}` when you should be using `PlotStyle ->{color1, color2, color3, color4}`.  So replace that option in your code with `PlotStyle-> Flatten[{Black,pftColor}]`

Comment: Evaluate is too deep in `Plot` to have an effect. But still this nested syntax of `PlotStyle` is not supported. `Flatten` those arguments. And inject the table with `With`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Mathematica 7 and I don't think I will be able to upgrade to 11 soon. I tried with flatten but I actually get the same exact figure but with a green color instead of the magenta.

Comment: @Kuba I tried to look at the `With` function but it's not clear to me how I should use it in this case. Also if you can think of another, more effective, syntax to produce the plot let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbhAdult` is not defined so here is a minimal example of how to fix your problems:

```
ClearAll[x];
g[x_] := x;
f = {x^2, x^3};
col = {Red, Blue};

Plot[Evaluate @ Flatten @ {g[x], f}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Flatten@{Black, col}]
```

[image]